# Is WebdriverJS a full featured alternative to the original selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I was looking for a java script based web automation framework and came across [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io/)

In the home page it says the following
.

> ✔ Provides over 50 useful actions to operate with your application
>
> ✔ Supports selenium tests in the cloud
>
> ✔ Compatible to all NodeJS test frameworks

It doesnt really say how does it stand when compared to the full features of the original selenium webdriver , questions like -

> 1. are all the selenium apis mapped yet
> 2. what am I going to miss if I decide to use it instead of selenium  webdriver ?
> 3. any other comparison with selenium or any other web automation frameworks

Note : I am not looking from a cloud testing point of view, just need a tool that I can use in my desktop to automate some test cases for HTML based websites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Currently not all but most of the JSONWire protocol commands are implemented (~90%). Missing ones like local_storage, application_cache will be implemented within `v2.0.0` which will get released within the next 2 or 3 weeks (hopefully)
2. Depends on what do expect.
3. see https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs/issues/138#issuecomment-32051980

Comment: Perhaps it'll be useful for you guys and people like me if you can put the info from the github page into the webdriverjs website :-)